# Visual studio 2013 - how to show rss news on start page?

Tags: rss, visual-studio-2013, feed, start-page

How to enable rss news feed on the home page visual studio 2013? Since it was in visual studio 2012.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa991992.aspx), the procedure is similar to VS2012:

> Go to the **Startup** options page (**Tools / Options, Environment**, **Startup**,
>   or type **startup** in the **Quick Launch** window). To change what is
>   displayed at startup, choose one of the options in the **At startup**
>   drop-down list. To change the RSS feed, change the URL in the **Start
>   page news channel** box.

The default settings in VS2012 are as follows so copy these to VS2013 settings:

[image: options]

Comment: In VS2013 you can't customize the Start Page from the IDE.

Answer (score 7):

The option to customize the news channel of VS Start Page has been removed.

To do so you will have to create a new page using the VS SDK : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee663382.aspx

You can also edit the  in links.XML file. (into you Common7\IDE\StartPages\en\ folder).

Comment: Its here: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0_Config\StartPage\NewsChannel` in regedit. source: http://stackoverflow.com/q/553392